# How To setfocus on spinner?

Tags: android, focus

I have spinner and edittext, and i want if spinner is selected can setfocus in edittext. I am already try, but not going to work, how to fix this?

This is my code :

```
edkontak1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                    sembunyikanKeyboard();
                    v.clearFocus();
                    spinnerkontak1.requestFocus();
                    spinnerkontak1.performClick();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

 spinnerkontak1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String jeniskontak1 = spinnerkontak1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(jeniskontak1.equals("--")){
                    edkontak1.setText("");
                    edkontak1.setEnabled(false);
                    tkontak2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tkontak3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tkontak4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tkontak5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else{
                    edkontak1.setEnabled(true);
                    tkontak2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spinnerkontak1.setFocusable(true);
                    spinnerkontak1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

private void sembunyikanKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager inputmanaget = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputmanaget.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add requestFocus() on spinner

Comment: Thank you sir, but this is just my mistake. I set on spinner request focus and on edittext setFocusable=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should implement request focus method `edkontak1.requestFocus();`

Comment: This is my first time using setFocus. Thank you sir, my logic is reversed.

Comment: @DennyKurniawan great, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct. But you have to add this line too.

```
spinnerkontak1.setFocusable(true);
```